# Feature Detect support for DOM Ranges (Modernizr)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range, modernizr

There was once a man who wrote a script which would let him do 'one-click-selection' of the contents of a span. His code relied on the almighty **$**, using jQuery's **browser detection**. It worked like a charm.

Then one fateful day, **jQuery 1.9** was released, and it **broke his code**, and heart. The browser detect was relegated to the stuff of legends, never to be seen again. So he foraged for new ways, and he came upon the **Modernizr** library. It was cool, it was thorough, it looked like it was what he wanted. Alas, it wasn't.

The library lacked the *one* feature he wanted, to feature detect if his browser supported the **DOM Range** object. He is befuddled by this odd oversight. Surely there is something he is missing somewhere.

Can you help him find the right tool to do a feature detect for **DOM Range**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just detect what you need. The following does make some assumptions (the existence of `document.createRange()` and `window.getSelection()` implying the existence of Range and selection methods, for example) but is a reasonable compromise.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dCvgU/

Code:

```
$("span").click(function() {
    var body = document.body, range, sel;
    if (typeof document.createRange != "undefined" &&
            typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(this);
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this code suffice?

```
var supportsRange = typeof Range === 'object' && typeof document.createRange === 'function' && typeof Selection === 'object' &&  typeof Selection.prototype.getRangeAt === 'function';

if ( supportsRange ) {
    //
}
```

Comment: hmm... pretty close, there is one tiny bit of problem:

old versions of IE have the TextRange, which are not accounted for here. 

Also, are there more variations of the Range object in other browsers (say Opera for example)

Comment: You could just keep adding to that test. It'll be lengthy but it should do it. For opera you can just test against window.Opera

Comment: I seem to remember reading somewhere that window.Opera is deprecated, but I can't seem to remember where.  It might be with their switch to webkit, but in that case your detection for opera wouldn't matter.

Comment: yeah... it's logical. 
Although I was expecting that maybe there was some support in Modernizr, but this would do just fine. Thanks :D

Comment: actually, I'd like to suggest an edit:

As of version 25, Google Chrome treats Range and Selection as a Native and Callable Function rather than an Object, which fails the if condition in two places.

In coffee style, here is what I'm using now:

`isStandard = Range? and document.createRange? and Selection? and Selection.prototype.getRangeAt?`

Comment: @Harsh: If you want to detect support for TextRange as well, you should put that in the question. In practice, every browser you're likely to care about supports at least one of DOM Range and TextRange.

Comment: @TimDown : yes, I got that point. The thing I'm trying to say is that Chrome (but not firefox or even chromium) treat Range and Selection as functions rather than objects, so the answer has to be modified a bit.

Comment: @Harsh: Testing the existence of `document.createRange` and `window.getSelection` is enough in practice

Comment: yes, that is correct, therefore I chose the other answer (for completeness and conciseness of the check).

Comment: Also, Opera supports Range and Selection for some time now if quirksmode and opera's own documentation is to be believed :D

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake, here is a more complete version of the two answers, wrapped as a jquery plugin.
The plugin supports all major browsers.

*(it's in coffescript, for js code, head to [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org))*

```
$.fn.selectText = () ->
  @each ->
    text = this
    # FF, Chrome, IE9+, and hopefully Opera
    if document.createRange? and window.getSelection?
      selection = window.getSelection()
      range = document.createRange()
      range.selectNodeContents text
      selection.removeAllRanges()
      selection.addRange range
    # <= IE8
    else if document.body.createTextRange?
      range = document.body.createTextRange()
      range.moveToElementText text
      range.select()
    # Safari
    else if window.getSelection?
      selection = window.getSelection()
      selection.setBaseAndExtent text, 0, text, 1
```